# secure Actionmailer so as to connect to gmail without sign-in prevention

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, actionmailer

I'm trying to use devise confirmable, and I've connected successfully to gmail, but rather than having an email sent from my gmail account, I get a sign-in prevention warning:

```
Someone just tried to sign in to your Google Account myemail@gmail.com from an app that doesn't meet modern security standards.
```

Is there a way to make the action mailer secure enough to meet Google's standards? I don't really want to lower the security settings on my gmail account.

Comment: Can you post a santized version of `config.action_mailer.smtp_settings` block from the environment you are running this in